# How was the equation re-written?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

This question is a part of inhomogeneous recurrence relations (IHR). The actual question was

> Find a solution to $a_n - a_{n-1} = 3(n-1)$ where $n \ge 1$ and $a_0 = 2$.

While going through the solution, the expression
$$3 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)X^n$$
was re-written as
$$3 \cdot \frac{X^2}{(1-X)^{2}}$$
I am not able to understand how this was done. What were the steps involved in this process of conversion?
**Update:**
The textbook says it is using pre-calculated values from this table.
But i do not see any correlation between what we are converting and what's available in the table.Need help understanding how this table was used for conversion

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic identity you should know is the geometric series ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Geometric_series)):
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\quad \text{ (for }|x|<1)$$
Therefore
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align*}
3\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)x^n&=3\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n\right)-3\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\right)\\
&=3x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\right)-3x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right)\\
&=3x\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
&=3x\left(\frac{1-(1-x)}{(1-x)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{3x^2}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks.This is neat.But i just read the next part of textbook and it says it is using values from the table shown above.How is this being done? ( sorry for the late reply)

Comment: The table tells you that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Therefore
$$3\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n-1)x^n=3x\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n-1)x^{n-1}=3x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=3x\cdot\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{3x^2}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: interesting.Thank you.

Comment: i was trying to convert this equation $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(n)(n-1)x^n$
i got struck at $X^2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty(n)(n-1)x^{n-2}$.

Comment: Oh.Ok. i think i solved it.
$X^2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty(n)(n-1)x^{n-2} = $
$X^2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty([n-2]+2)([n-2]+1)x^{n-2}$ 
and then use the $(n+2)*(n+1)$ formula.Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

You can just look at the Taylor expansion of the function.

---

Without going into analysis too much, here some fact it the general realm of problems you deal with here:

For $|\,x\,|<1$, you have the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Geometric_series#Formula)

$\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$

and it comes in handy to know that if you have another function given by a series

$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n,$

then multiplication by $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ acts as follows:

$\dfrac{1}{1-x}\cdot f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n c_k\right) x^n$

You can see this by multiplying out the series written out to the highest relevant order, and I also advise you to read the good book Generatinfunctionlogy by Wilf. He has it public [here (link to pdf)](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf).

Now since

$\dfrac{x^2}{1-x}=x^2\,(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)=x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\dots$

is itself a function with series representation with coefficients $c_k$ given by $0,0,1,1,1,1,1,\dots$, you get

$\dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=2}^n 1\right) x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(n-1\right) x^n.$

Comment: Thank You.But i need to use the table shown above to convert the equation.How to do that?

Comment: @Pradeep: I see your question has been answered. A general tip: Write spaces after points. Not "Thank You.But i", but rather "Thank you. But I".